# How do we "gift" a gift?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

What is a suitable word which fits the blank in "gift _________ ceremony"?

In general the word "giving" can fill the blanks, but I feel there may be a more suitable phrase we can use. Suggestions?

Research:

- [presentation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/presentation), feels kind of *repetitive*
- [benefaction](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/benefaction), sounds like *superiority*
- [handout](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/handout), again, sense of *superiority*

*Context: If it matters, this is regarding the wedding gift for a colleague.*

Comment: May I ask for a comment related to the DV?

Comment: As per my tour of the [help] page, I can see _"Questions on the following topics are welcomed here:

Word choice and usage"_, so can anybody help me in improving the question?

Comment: I don't see how this question is qualitatively different from the many single-word request questions we field at this site. The poster provides context for the word in question, which should avoid its running afoul of the "ideal words" pitfall. Is the whole problem that the poster tagged the question for "alternative-words" instead of for "single-word-request"? It's hard to imagine an SWR that isn't "primarily opinion based."

Answer (score 2):

Other words that might fit include, for instance award, presentation or presenting among many.

'a gift ceremony' with nothing in the gap might serve equally well but none could be as suitable as 'gift giving…' because that's what it was *designed* for, so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

The term *[bestow](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/bestow)* is often used.

> Confer or present (an honor, right, or gift)
>
> *the office was bestowed on him by the chief of state*
>
> *thank you for this honor that you have bestowed upon me*
>
> figurative *she bestowed her nicest smile on Jim*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*